# Error when changing the order of subtraction of of 2 arrays in python

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to calculate the residual sum of squares for a given data.

The name of the data-set is **test**.

The original values are **test['price']**, the predicted values are **predict_0** that I obtain from a self defined function:

```
def predict_output(feature_matrix, weights):
    predictions = np.dot(feature_matrix, weights)
    return predictions
```

My code for calculating the RSS is:

```
predict_0 =  predict_output(simple_test_feature_matrix, initial_weights)
   errors_0 = predict_0-test['price']
   rss_0 = (errors_0**2).sum()
```

This return the correct answer, however, if I interchange the order in which I am subtracting the matrices to: **errors_0 = test['price']-predict_0** I get a weird output.

Could anyone explain why that happens?

Comment: _"I get a weird output."_  When diagnosing computer problems, vagueness is not a virtue.  What output do you see?  Why do you classify it as  "weird"?  Can you show us data that demonstrates the "weird" behavior?  What type is your data?  You say you are working with "matrices"?  Are they numpy or native python or what?

Comment: My bad. I'm working with numpy matrices, what I mean by weird is that when executing: errors_0 = test['price']-predict_0, the result I get is a collection of arrays, each of the same length as 'test' and each array contains one 'errors' result. That is, array one of the output is 4229 rows big (the length of test) and contains the value of 'errors[0]' repeated throughout. This happens for every single value of 'errors'. One array for each value.

Comment: What is the shape of `test['price']`?  What is the shape of `predict_0`?  Numpy has arrays and numpy has matrices and they are different.  You have used both words.  Which are you using?  What is the type of each array, `array.dtype`?

Comment: I just rechecked, and sorry for the misinformation, I am working with arrays only in numpy and not matrices. `predict_0.dtype` returns float64, `test['price'].dtype` returns float. Both `predict_0` and `test['price']` have the same shape (4229, ). Also, while `predict_0` is a 'numpy.ndarray', `test['price']` is a 'graphlab.data_structures.sarray.SArray'

Comment: Yes, just edited my earlier comment to answer those as well.

Comment: Very good.  That is informative:  you are using `graphlab`.  I can't try to reproduce the problem because I don't have graphlab.  In python, however, objects get to redefine subtraction as they wish with the `__sub__` and `__rsub__` methods.  So, it is very possible that, if one array is numpy and the other is graphlab, that `x-y` has no relation  to `y-x`.

Comment: I would suggest converting both arrays to the same type (both numpy _or_ both graphlab) and trying subtract again.

Comment: Alright, Thanks a lot!